# いいがと、Pattern meaning?

Tags: particle-と, particle-が

I am reading the Japanese translation of Matilda. I am stuck on understanding the following sentence:

> 事故にでもあわなければ**いいがと**、ミセス・フェルプスはそれが気がかりだったが、けっきょく、口出ししないことに決めた。

What is the meaning of が in the emboldened section of the quote? Would it not work perfectly as well without this particle?

If this is a common grammatical construct, I would also much appreciate any further examples of its usage, though these are not necessary for an accepting answer!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This が marks the end of a clause and technically means "but" in the typical way that Japanese end sentences with が or けど etc.

The following と is the quotative と.  So there is a suggestion that this is her inner dialogue as she's thinking through the situation and what to do.